# Redirect m.example.com to m.example.com/subdir

Tags: apache, redirect

how do i redirect m.example.com to m.example.com/subdir
i am using the following code for the same but it is getting cyclic and not redirecting properly

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://m.example.com/subdir [R=301,L]
```

I  cannot also use:

```
redirect 301 / http://m.example.com/subdir
```

as my main www site will also get redirected

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition so it doesn't redirect if the request is already for /subdir/. Add this somewhere above your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir
```

You're also missing a backreference in your rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://m.example.com/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the **only** thing you want to redirect is requests for the root (URI=/), then you don't need the extra rewrite condition, only change your regular expression in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/subdir [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect just / but not anything under it you can use something like this in your `m.example.com` `<VirtualHost>`

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://m.example.com/subdir/
```

Alternatively, if you want to redirect everything into `subdir` except requests for `subdir` itself you could use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com/subdir$1 [R=301,L]
```